# How to add a 3 lines in a file using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-script

I have a file, that file contain 10 lines. And now I want to add 3 lines to end of the file using shell script. After add lines, If I run the script again I don't want to add same lines again.

filename : test.txt

```
first line : **hello this rajkumar** 
Second line: **good morningt**           
Third line : **Thank you**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply quote it and redirect:

```
% echo 'first line : **hello this rajkumar** 
        Second line: **good morningt**           
        Third line : **Thank you**' >>./file
```

Or for safer handling of quotes you can con`cat`enate a `here-document` with `stdin` and redirect `stdout` to your file:

```
% cat <<\LINES >>./file
> first line : **hello this rajkumar**
> Second line: **good morningt**
> Third line : **Thank you**
> LINES
```

If you want to, as I think I take your meaning, avoid writing the same line to a file twice, the following makes for a pretty quick and painless check:

```
% sort <<\LINES <~/file | uniq -u >>~/file
> ...
> LINES
```

When the `-u` option is specified `uniq` will print to its `stdout` only - yup, you guessed it - unique lines as read from its `stdin`. Kind of annoying though that it doesn't collate its input and so we need the `sort` utility to do so for us. I say it's annoying only because even if the compared files are in the same order already they're bound to stream in to `stdin` like 1,2,3,1,2,3 rather than the 1,1,2,2,3,3 it requires. Also, `sort -u` does almost exactly what we need *except* that it doesn't omit matches and so 1,2,3,4,1,2,3 becomes 1,2,3,4. Combine the two, though, and from 1,2,3.5,4,0,1,2,3 you get only 0,3.5,4.

Anyway, it gets the job done.

And then there's `diff`, which requires a little more configuring to print only line contents:

```
diff --new-group-format='%>' \
     --changed-group-format='%>' \
     --old-line-format= \
     --unchanged-line-format= \
     ~/file \
     /dev/fd/3 \
3<<\LINES >>~/file
> first line : **hello this rajkumar**
> Second line: **good morningt**
> Third line : **Thank you**
> LINES
```

First of all, I should mention that while it is almost certainly available for any unix you could wish, `diff` isn't necessarily already installed on your system. Probably it is, but maybe not.

Also, `diff` doesn't like `stdin` - it wants to read from at least two actual filesystem paths for comparison, which is why I specify the `3` redirection operator above and hand `diff /dev/fd/3` as an argument.

By default `diff` prints a lot of information you may not necessarily want to write to your file, and that's why I demonstrate its use with all of the operands above. It does provide a `--suppress-common-lines` option, which is handy, but additional `diff` information is also included in its output and the option doesn't play nicely with arguments omitting it - so we have to specify all or none.

As shown, `diff` will print only the line from `%>` /dev/fd/3 - its rightmost file-argument - if it detects a common line between the two files has changed and only new-lines it detects from `%>` same. It will print nothing at all for old or unchanged lines, so appending its output to its leftmost argument - here `~/file` - would result in identical behavior to the above `uniq` command.

Comment: if i run again, i dont want to add same line in a file

Comment: So you're asking how to add a line to the end of a file only if an identical line is not already present therein? If so, I can show you, but I'm not clear on your meaning...?

Answer (score 0):

You can append to end of a file by using `>>`, Example:

```
echo "What ever you want" >> file
```

IMHO, you should read bash manpage, section `REDIRECTION`:

```
Appending Redirected Output
       Redirection of output in  this  fashion  causes  the  file  whose  name
       results  from  the expansion of word to be opened for appending on file
       descriptor n, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if  n  is  not
       specified.  If the file does not exist it is created.

       The general format for appending output is:

              [n]>>word
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following construct to check if the contents of `file.txt` are present in another file, and if not add it.

#### Example

Say I have the following 2 files:

```
$ more file.txt afile.txt 
::::::::::::::
file.txt
::::::::::::::
first line : **hello this rajkumar**
Second line: **good morningt**
Third line : **Thank you**
::::::::::::::
afile.txt
::::::::::::::
blah
blah
```

Now if we use the following one liner:

```
$ if ! grep -qFxf file.txt afile.txt; then cat file.txt  >> afile.txt; fi
```

We should see lines getting added to `afile.txt`.

```
$ more afile.txt 
blah
blah
first line : **hello this rajkumar**
Second line: **good morningt**
Third line : **Thank you**
```

If I run the `if ...` one liner again we should see no changes made to `afile.txt`.

```
$ if ! grep -qFxf file.txt afile.txt; then  cat file.txt  >> afile.txt; fi
$ more afile.txt 
blah
blah
first line : **hello this rajkumar**
Second line: **good morningt**
Third line : **Thank you**
```

#### Details

The `if` is pretty self explanatory, the only other interesting thing going on here is the argument to `if`. We're looking for situations where the `if` statement fails, and so we're adding the contents of `file.txt` to `afile.txt`.

The switches to `grep`, `-qFxf` tell `grep` to be:

- `-q` - quiet, don't display any matches to the grep only report them via the return status.
- `-F` - Fixed strings in the file `file.txt`.
- `-x` - Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
- `-f` - Obtain a pattern from file `file.txt`.

Comment: There's a problem with this - and I know because I initially wrote it all up myself before testing it - grep will count as a match a line in `file.txt` that completely includes a line in `afile.txt.` This means that 'line 1 AND' in `file.txt` does not get added to `afile.txt` if it includes `line 1`. Even `line AND 1` would be omitted.

Comment: @mikeserv - if I understand you, you're saying that if a line from `file.txt` is contained as a substring in a pre-existing line in `afile.txt` it will erroneously match? That won't happen b/c of the switches I've made use of with `grep`.

Comment: I know the switches you used and - they're identical to the ones I tested, and yes it will. What's more, if one line is not in `file.txt` its entire contents are dumped to `afile.txt`.

Comment: @mikeserv - rather than us debate what the OP "might want" let's wait for him to come back and provide further details. This Q is already poorly asked and this OP has already had another Q on the site tonight heavily critiqued b/c it was lacking in details. You've provided your approach and I've provided mine. If the OP has further requirements I'm fine with sitting on this until then. I'm not going to build a yacht if all he wants is a row boat.

Comment: You could `while read` it, or even `(IFS="$newline" ; set -- $(cat file.txt) ; for l ; grep "$l" file ... done )` for line by line operation, but it doesn't solve the problem that grep will treat the matches inclusively and so long as any line in `file.txt` contains entirely a line in `afile.txt` it will not be added - even if it contains additional information.

Comment: @mikeserv - again you're guessing at potential requirements. The Q needs to specify more of this if the OP would like a more fully functional solution. These meet the loose requirements that he's provided thus far.

Comment: Ok, I was still writing that last before I read your last. I agree.

Comment: @mikeserv - look at the OP before willing to devote more of your own resources. This Q is of marginal value to the site to begin with, and he's already had several Q's DV'd and closed b/c they're poorly written and lacking in details.

Comment: @mikeserv - yes the lag in comments can be annoying 8-).

Comment: Well, I only post here at all because I'm trying to learn how to use computers. I learn best solving problems and thinking things through so this is easy for me. Everything I write is for entirely selfish reasons - I devote my resources to my own edification, marginal or not.

Comment: @mikeserv - same here, I'm teaching myself 1st and also trying to help others.

Comment: want to add 3 lines in a file. If i again run a script it dont add the same line. how to do?

Comment: Dude, I already answered that. Twice.

Comment: @mikeserv - looks like a troll, see what  I mean?

Comment: I definitely see what you mean. Still, I learned how to get diff to quit spitting all of those carets at me.

Comment: @mikeserv - this guy has had his account suspended here and apparently on AskUbuntu too.

Comment: Why? What did he do?

Comment: Irregular voting for one, asking poor Q's for another. On this site that feature of SE is disabled, but on AU if you continuously ask weak Q's your account can be suspended.

Answer (score 0):

You can also grab the last three lines of your file to a temp file and diff that with your expected lines.  Append if the diff fails.

```
#!/bin/bash
LINES=('**hello this rajkumar**' '**good morningt**' '**Thank you**')
tail -3 afile > /tmp/afile.$$.1
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "${LINES[@]}" > /tmp/afile.$$.2
if ! diff /tmp/afile.$$.1 /tmp/afile.$$.2 >/dev/null; then printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "${LINES[@]}" >> afile; fi
rm /tmp/afile.$$.1 /tmp/afile.$$.2
```